# Why is this program giving me a SIGFPE?

Tags: c

I am getting SIGFPE Error in the below program and cannot think of a way to remove it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int fact(unsigned long int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
        return 1;
    return n*fact(n-1);
}


int main(){
    int t,r,x,y,z,sum=0,n;

    scanf("%d",&t);

    for(int l=0; l<t; l++){

        scanf("%d",&n );

        if(n%2==0){
            for(int j=n,i=0,k=n; k>=0&&j>0;i++, j++,k-=2){
                x=fact(n-i);
                y=fact(k);
                z=fact(n-k-i);
                sum=sum+  (x)/(y*z);
            }
            printf("%d\n",sum );
        }

        if(n%2!=0){
            for(int j=n,i=0,k=n; k>=1&&j>0;i++, j++,k-=2){
                x=fact(n-i);
                y=fact(k);
                z=fact(n-k-i);
                sum=sum+  (x)/(y*z);

            }
            printf("%d\n",sum);
        }
        sum=0;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to calculate a series which needs factorial but this is giving me SIGFPE error. I use `35` as input.

link to the question: [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYpL5.png)

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GF0zt.png)

Comment: Check to make sure you're not dividing by 0.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show an example of input that triggers the problem.

Comment: checked, I guess I am getting this error due to the factorial part http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow but I cannot think of a way to remove it.

Comment: It is working fine on my laptop compiler but gives error on website hackerearth.

Comment: What is the input that triggers the error??

Comment: I don't know cuz the website doesn't show all the inputs.

Comment: If I give 35 as in input it give error in my laptop too.

Comment: Note that 32-bit integers can only store up to factorial 12; 64-bit integers up to factorial 20.  Anything bigger probably requires `double`, or multiprecision integer arithmetic (meaning a special library).

Comment: Factorials of 34 ad over will be zero for [unsigned ints and for many signed int implementations](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151214-00/?p=92621). If you must calculate binomial coefficients, [don't use the explicit formula](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130508-00/?p=4423/).

Comment: @PushkarSoni could you tell us what the program is actually supposed to do?

Comment: I want to calculate the above series which gives the answer to my question.

Comment: https://www.hackerearth.com/challenge/college/y18lnmiit/algorithm/30586d77496b46a7aeaa4f6190885edc/

Comment: You state -- twice -- that this gives you a SIGFPE **on compilation**. I am pretty sure that isn't the case... (and have edited the question accordingly.)

Comment: @PushkarSoni your link isn't useful, you need to login. Please [edit] your question and put all relevant information _there_.

Comment: how to upload screen shot

Comment: here you go: `35!` is `10333147966386144929666651337523200000000`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky any suggestions how could I calculate that factorial part in inside the for loop, such that first i calculate when (i=0..etc). so that the ratio will come out fine in every step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Jabberwocky answer.

Overflow is not the only reason, yoh have overflow of a 'round' number...

fact(34) returns the amazing result of 0.

If it was a `uint64` return value and arg

```
unsigned long long fact(unsigned long long n)
```

and you print the result with

```
printf("%llx",x);
```

you'll get the result:  445da75b00000000

Cast it to int and you'll get a perfect 0.

It is logical since you have multiply a lot of even numbers and some of the are even power of 2.

## You just need 32 2s multiplies to reach this result:

- 2,6,10,14,18,22,26,30,34 each give you one 2 so you have 9 2s
- 4,12,20,28 each give you 4, which is 2*2, so it gives you 8 2s, so you already have 17 2s
- 8,24 give you 8 which is 2*2*2, so you have more 6 2s, and total is 23 2s
- 16 give you more 4 2s, so you have 27 2s
- 32 give you more 5 2s, so you have exactly 32 2s.

Answer (score 4):

35! exceeds the capacity of an `unsigned int` on your platform by far.

What happens then is that `fact(35)` returns 0, which results in a division by 0 hence the SIGFPE (**f**loating **p**oint **e**xception).

Consider using the `unsigned long long` type, but this won't help for 35 either, because 35! is really huge.

Comment: is there a way to do those factorial calculations?

Answer (score 0):

In your program, you calculate the binomial coefficient C(n, k) for each possible number of two-task days. The formula is simple:

```
C(n, k) = n! / (k! * (n - k)!)
```

but using this formula directly has several problems: The intermediate results, namely the factorials, overflow quickly. Unsigned 32-bit integers can hold factoials up to 12!, unsigned 64-bit integers can hold up to 20!, but after that you will need bignum libraries. The problem statement says that the number of tasks, N, is at most 80. I believe this limit was chosen so that you can do all calculations with `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>`.

There are other problems; [Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130508-00/?p=4423/) outlines them more elegantly than I can. He also proposes a simple way to calculate binomial coefficients, which you can adopt:

```
uint64_t binom(uint64_t n, uint64_t k)
{
    uint64_t c = 1u;
    uint64_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        c *= n - i;
        c /= i + 1;
    }

    return c;
}
```

Oh, and you don't need to distinguish between odd and even N's.

And there's something strange about the challenge: N is the only parameter for each testcase and it can range from 1 to 80, but there can be up to 10,000 test cases. If there are more than 80 cases, N will repeat. Maybe they want you to memoize the results in an array, so that the first time you calculate bthe result, store it and the next time you have to calculate for the same N again, just use the precalculated value. This saves time, and "Time limit exceeded" is a very frequent error in online contests.

You could also try to calculate the first couple of results, say for N from 1 to 10, and print them. Notice a pattern? See, you didn't need the binomial coefficients at all. `:)`

Comment: I couldn't understand your solution. I did what Raymond chen explained in the link, but I couldn't solve the problem Now I am getting floating point error.  I have uploaded a screenshot. In order to avoid division by zero I even inserted if conditions but still it gives floating point error, I can't find a solution to the error and not sure why I don't have to distinguish between odd and even cuz the series it seems to follow, goes to some limited terms and it's different for odd and even N's. would you please look into my code, so that I could be clear of this concepts. Thank you.

Comment: Your screenshot shows essentially the same solution as before, with the same shortcomings: The individual factorials overflow, even if the binomial coefficent can be represented. That's the point of Raymond Chen's article: The simple formula looks pretty, but isn't useful when calculating the binomial coefficient. The function I posted doesn't help with factorials. It calculates C(n, k) without overflowing for many cases where your formula overflows. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) calls this the multiplicative formula.)

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/7YEGsz) is a program that calculates the solutions for all n from 1 to 80. If you lok closely, you'll see that this is the Fibinacci series, and if you think about it, it's easy to see why: s(n) is s(n + 1) plus one two-task-day plus s(n - 2) plus two two-day tasks. So to solve this task, it is sufficient to calulate the Fibonacci series up to 80. (But don't use the recursive recurrence.)

Comment: (Also, please refrain from posting code as screenshots. It's pretty, but being able to copy and paste text is more useful.)